# How to bundle angular 2 html templates and css when deploying without using gulp/grunt/angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, browserify, systemjs

I've seen a number of tutorials about how to use various tools (systemJS, browserify) for bundling angular 2 applications.  These tutorials always just inline the html in the component.ts file.  When your HTML and CSS are in external files, it fails to find them in the browser (for reasons that are clear).

Is there anything I can use to deal with the associated html and css files as well?  I'm aware that gulp/grunt/angular cli have solutions for this but I'm interested to know if there's a way without having to adopt one of these systems.  For everything else I'm doing, npm scripts have been sufficient.

I'm fine using browserify/systemJS for this, or another npm module that I can just include as a script without having to migrate my whole project to angular cli or rewrite my build processes.

Comment: This looks like a standalone tool for doing that https://github.com/pablodenadai/angular2-inline-template-style

Comment: I googled so much for something like this and was unable to find it.  My googling failed me!  Thanks very much.  I'll check it.

Comment: using `ng2-inline -o build/inlined -b build build/**/*.js` it does this for the first java script file it encounters and then quits with no errors.

Comment: It also doesn't respect relative html/css - like if you have a component `account/account.component.ts` that references a stylesheet as `styleUrls: ['account.component.css']` it will look for that css file in the base folder you provide, not the folder relative to the component.

Comment: I haven't used that package, but I think you'd have better luck moving to angular-cli tbh, and you'd probably spend less time doing that than trying to inline the stuff manually.

Comment: Yeah I'm coming around to that line of thinking.  In the midst of trying to convert it now...

Comment: OK - you're right, that was easier in the end.  Still have to adapt a bunch of my scripts but at least I'm making progress.